# DPDK l2fwd with multiple RX/TX queue in KVM

Tags: networking, qemu, kvm, dpdk

I wanted to try-out multiple RX/TX queue in KVM (Guest: CentOS). I have compiled DPDK (version: 18.05.1) and inserted igb_uio driver (bound two interface to it).

I am trying client to server connection (private).

> client (eth1: 10.10.10.2/24) <--> (eth1) CentOS VM (DPDK: 18.05.1)
> (eth2) <--> server (eth1: 10.10.10.10/24)

VM manages both interface directly in passthrough mode (macvtap - passthrough).

```
<interface type='direct' trustGuestRxFilters='yes'>
<source dev='ens1' mode='passthrough'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<driver name='vhost' queues='2'/>
</interface>
```

When l2fwd applications started with single RX & TX queue (default change) & no-mac-updating. Client & server connectivity works perfectly.

I made some changes to try multiple RX/TX queues with l2fwd application.
I could see that ARP is not getting resolved at either end. VM doesn't receive any packets afterwards.

Can someone point me to the document to use multiple RX/TX queues which can verify my changes? Does multiple RX/TX queues work in VM environment? I have seen others also complaining about it.

I am newbie in DPDK world. Any help will be useful. Thank you.

**Edited (Adding more details):**
I am configuring ethernet device with 1 RX queue and 2 TX queues in l2fwd example.

```
uint16_t q = 0;
uint16_t no_of_tx_queues = 2;
        
// Configuring Ethernet Device
rte_eth_dev_configure(portid, 1, no_of_tx_queues, &local_port_conf);
            
// Configuring Rx Queue
ret = rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(portid, 0, nb_rxd, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(portid), &rxq_conf, l2fwd_pktmbuf_pool);

// Configuring 2 TX Queue
for(q = 0; q < no_of_tx_queues; q++) {
    ret = rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(portid, q, nb_txd, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(portid), &txq_conf);
}
```

I am reading packets from single RX queue: Queue-id: 0 (as setup earlier).

```
nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(portid, 0, pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST);
```

I am seeing that some packets are coming and forwarded to other interface but some are not. For ICMP (ping), I can see ARP is forwarded but ICMP echo request is not read by l2fwd.

**Solution what I found:**
I have configured 2 RX & 2 TX queues in l2fwd. I can read ICMP request from second RX queue (Queue-id: 1) and forward too. With that, client-to-server connectivity is working as expected. You can't configure 1 RX and 2 TX queues. You need to **configure an equal number of RX & TX queues** (in the KVM world).

**The question here is:**
Even I have configured 1 RX queue & 2 TX queue. Why few packets are coming on Queue-id: 1 (which is not configured & not read by l2fwd application).
It is observed in KVM (running on CentOS) environment. I have checked the same on ESXI, I can see all packets are read from single queue (Queue-id: 0) and forwarded.

Why?? Please explain. Is there any way I can turn off load balancing (of packet transmitted on two RX queues) in KVM so that I can receive all the packets on single queue?

Comment: Here are few references which I used (but couldn't fix my problem):
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_real_virtual.html
https://mails.dpdk.org/archives/dev/2014-July/004487.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DPDK's Vhost multiple queues test plan with all the command line arguments used: 
https://doc.dpdk.org/dts/test_plans/vhost_multi_queue_qemu_test_plan.html

There are no much details in the question, so the only suggestion I have is to make sure multiple queues work first and then run `l2fwd` on top of that. If the guest OS does not work with multiple queues, DPDK won't fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Andriy, I have added my finding and details which talks about the problem and a workaround to it. But, I couldn't understand why was it happening. Let me know if you can add some details here. Thx.

Comment: Did not you start the VM with 2 queues? can you also share the command line used for DPDK l2fwd too?